# Printing x bytes from a text file per line until EOF

Tags: c, file-io, fread

So I have a file that is read. The user can specify how many bytes at a time to print out.
Currently I have:

```
while(fread(buffer, bytes, 1, txtFile) != '\0')
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

However, it cuts off the last line if it reaches EOF first. For example, if `bytes = 12` , this prints:

```
How the migh
ty have fall
```

...but I want it to print out:

```
How the migh
ty have fall
en!
```

instead. What is the right way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fread` function returns the number of *items* read from the file.  This call:

```
fread(buffer, bytes, 1, txtFile)
```

means to try and read an item of size `bytes`.  If it succeeds the result is `1`, if it fails the result is `0`.  The fact that you wrote `!= '\0'` suggests that maybe you misunderstand the return value. It seems to work for earlier lines because `0 == '\0'`, but it is a misleading way to write `0`.

Since there were only `4` bytes left in the file, it failed to read an item of size `12` bytes and so your loop exits.

Another major problem is that you call `printf("%s"` however you do not supply a string as argument. There's a difference between a *string* and an array of char. A string ends in a null terminator and this is how the `printf` function knows when to stop printing.

If you read items of size `1` instead then you can fix both of these problems, e.g.:

```
for (size_t n_read; (n_read = fread(buffer, 1, bytes, txtFile)) > 0; )
{
    buffer[n_read] = '\0';
    puts(buffer);
}
```

NB. make sure `buffer` is allocated to have at least `bytes + 1` bytes in it.

Answer (score 1):

Original code fails as the least read was not 12 bytes long, so `fread()` returned 0.

`printf("%s\n", buffer);` is bad as `buffer` was not explicitly `'\0'` terminated.

To fix:

After each `fread()`, append a null character.  Also reo-order `fread()` parameters  to note partial reads.

```
size_t bytes = 12;
char buffer[bytes + 1];  // or char buffer[12 + 1];
size_t cnt;

while((cnt = fread(buffer, sizeof *buffer, bytes, txtFile)) > 0)
  buffer[cnt] = '\0';
  printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
```

Another approach is to simply print the data read as an array of `char` rather than as a string.

```
size_t bytes = 12;
char buffer[bytes];  // or char buffer[12];
size_t cnt;

while((cnt = fread(buffer, sizeof *buffer, bytes, txtFile)) > 0)
  for (size_t i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    fputc(buffer[i], stdout);
  }
  fputc('\n', stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because in the last line `'\0'` is the 4th byte and hence condition under **while** **loop** fails, exiting **while**. The solution is to print **buffer values** outside **while** also so as to print the last 3 bytes.

Demo:

```
while(fread(buffer, bytes, 1, txtFile) != '\0')
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it prints `en!have fall` instead of just `en!`?

Comment: Yes, the reason is every time buffer is filled new values, old values are overwritten. In this case your old values are `ty have fall` and only `ty ` are overwritten, rest remain same. Try `puts(buffer)` instead of 2nd `print` statement.

Comment: Thanks, but it still prints out `en!have fall`. Is there a better way around this problem?

Comment: clear the buffer to all '\0' after each call to printf()